# Bootstrap 4 Carousel 3 items move advance 1

Tags: html, css

Sorry to be a pain. I might have been staring at my code for way to long but I am trying to implement a Bootstrap Carousel into my website that will show 3 and then progress one. I am currently following the code sniper at: https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8 but can only get it to show one and progress one at a time.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Many thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="keywords" content="THE CARE COMPANY (SW) LTD, home care, care, care company, the, company, jobs, care jobs, TORBAY, DEVON, kingsbridge, totnes, plymouth, Care in Torbay , care Torbay, Care torquay, Torbay care , Care for eldery torbay, Torquay, the care company, home care services, home care medical, come care near me, home care elderly, home care agency, caregiver, home health care, respite care, home health aide, homecare, home care services, health, healthcare, assisted living, caregiver, respite care">
  <meta name="description" content="Delivering professional home care &amp; live-in care services. The Care Company provides bespoke respite care, dementia care, Alzheimer's care &amp; much more." class="">

  <title>The Care Company (SW) LTD</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom fonts  -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles -->
  <link href="css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script>
    $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var minPerSlide = 3;
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
});
</script>
</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top" style="font-size: 1rem !IMPORTANT">The Care Company (SW) LTD</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Our Expertise
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #6B244D !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">How Does Our Care Work</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Our CAREGivers</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Partnerships and professionals</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Our Care Options</a>
        </div>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Home Care Services
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #6B244D !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Companionship</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Home Help and Housekeeping</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Personal Care</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Dementia Care Including Alzheimer's desease</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Choosing The Right Care For You</a>
        </div>
      </li>
             <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
         Advice and Support
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #6B244D !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Cost Of Care</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">FAQ'S</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">How To Age Well</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Understanding And Preparing For Home Care</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Choosing The Right Care For You</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Nutrition</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Preventing Hospitalisation</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Community Involvement</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Alzheimers and Dementia Care</a>
        </div>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
         About Us
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #6B244D !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Executive Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Community Involvement</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Awards</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">What People Say About Us</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">Why Choose The Care Company (SW) LTD</a>
        </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
         Join Our Team
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color: #6B244D !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white !IMPORTANT;">#YouCanCare</a>
        </div>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">Getting Started</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#">News & Events</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="masthead v-header">

      <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <video src="video/vid.mp4" autoplay="yes" loop="yes">
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="header-overlay"></div>
    <div class="header-content text-md-center container">
        <h1 class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase" style="margin-bottom: 2px !IMPORTANT">Welcome To The Care Company (SW) LTD</h1>
           <p style="color: white !IMPORTANT">Supporting Independence At Home</p>
        <p>Our home care services not only provide you with the care you want, where and when you want it, we strive to keep you in control. It is your decisions, your life, your way.</p>
        <h2 class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5" style="color: white !IMPORTANT"></h2>
        <p>Call on: 01548 521789</p>
        <a href="#projects" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger"  >Join Our Team</a>
        <a href="#wjs" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Find Home Care</a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- About Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="text-black mb-4">Supported at home the<img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/words/you.jpg" width="30%" alt="way you want"></h1>
          <p class="text-black" >We understand that home is where you feel the happiest. If you want to stay living comfortably at home, you can live well, your way with The Care Company (SW) LTD.
              <br><br>
Home Instead has been at the forefront of specialised home care for the elderly and supporting those being cared for and their families for many years. Founded on personal experience, these family values remain at the core of everything we do 24 years on.
<br><br>
Our award-winning care at home fits around your life - it’s tailored, it’s flexible and it’s adaptable. Whether you’re looking for help getting dressed and showered, help around the house or companionship, Home Instead’s trained CAREGivers are perfectly matched to you.
<br><br>
We believe age should be celebrated and that everybody should be able to live happily, comfortably and independently at home.
<br><br>
Start your Home Instead journey today.
              <br><br><br>
        <a href="aboutUs.php" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" style="margin-bottom: -35px !IMPORTANT">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h1 class="text-black">Caring</h1>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">– It sounds obvious, but it’s what we do and why we do it.
<br><br>
– “We are compassionate, dedicated, considerate and supportive.”</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1 class="text-black">Trustworthy</h1>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">– We deliver a high standard of care, with integrity, through people who are passionate about what they do.
<br><br>
– “We are reliable, safe and diligent"</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1 class="text-black">Positive</h1>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">–  We endeavour to encourage optimism and positive outcomes because we are enthusiastic about what we do.
<br><br>
– “We are pragmatic, tenacious, willing and conscientious”</p>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </section>

    <!-- Looking For Staff Section -->
  <section id="wjs" class="wjs-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <p class="text-black" style="font-size: 20px">
“ There is a real feeling of assurance that the person you love and care for is being taken care of in your absence. That’s what Home Instead does. My aunt hates to see her CAREGivers go. There are times she probably would like to see them more than me. ’’
              <br><br>
              Bon Jove - Clients Family
              <br><br>
              Read more client testimonials:
              <br><br>
        <a href="#contactUs" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" style="margin-bottom: -35px !IMPORTANT">Testimonials</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

     <!-- Why Join Us Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
       <h1 class="text-black mb-4">Services</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
    <h2 class="text-black"><img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/words/rcare.png" width="65%" alt="Respite Care"></h2>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">– It sounds obvious, but it’s what we do and why we do it.
<br><br>
– “We are compassionate, dedicated, considerate and supportive.” 

  </div>
      </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
    <h2 class="text-black"><img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/words/hcare.png" width="65%" alt="Hourly Care"></h2>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">– It sounds obvious, but it’s what we do and why we do it.
<br><br>
– “We are compassionate, dedicated, considerate and supportive.” 
  </div>
      </div>
  <div class="column">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
    <h2 class="text-black"><img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="img/words/ccare..png" width="65%" alt="Complex Care"></h2>
      <br>
      <p class="text-black">– It sounds obvious, but it’s what we do and why we do it.
<br><br>
– “We are compassionate, dedicated, considerate and supportive.” 
  </div>
      </div>
</div>
        <h3 class="text-black mb-4">To view all our services please click below:</h3>
      <a href="#contactUs" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" style="margin-bottom: -35px !IMPORTANT">All Services</a><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
  </section>

    <!-- contact us Section -->
  <section id="contactUs" class="signup-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center">
<br><br>
          <h2 class="text-black mb-5">Contact Us:</h2>
            <p>You can either contact us via the form below or by post to: <br>The Care Company (SW) LTD, Little Spires, Totnes, Devon, TQ9 7QE <br> Tel: 01548 521789</p>

          <form class="form-inline d-flex" action="contact_post.php"method="post">
            <input type="test" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactFN" placeholder="Enter First Name *">
            <input type="text" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactLN" placeholder="Enter Last Name *">
            <input style="width: 100% !IMPORTANT; margin-top: 30px !IMPORTANT" type="text" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactCN" placeholder="Enter Subject">
            <input type="email" style="margin-top: 30px !IMPORTANT" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactE" placeholder="Enter Contact Email Address *">
            <input type="number" style="margin-top: 30px !IMPORTANT" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactN" placeholder="Enter Contact Number *">
              <textarea style="width: 100% !IMPORTANT; margin-top: 30px !IMPORTANT" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" id="contactM" class="form-control flex-fill mr-0 mr-sm-2 mb-3 mb-sm-0" id="contactM" placeholder="Let us know how we can help"></textarea>
              <br>
              <p>By clicking submit I consent to The Care Company (SW) LTD using my data for marketing purposes. I have read and accept the <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></p>
              <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px !IMPORTANT" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Submit</button>
          </form>
            <br>
            <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- quick page Section -->
  <!-- quick page Section -->
  <section id="about" class="about-section text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <h1 class="text-black mb-4">Awards & Affiliates</h1>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=5">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card card-body">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/380?text=6">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next w-auto" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
  </a>

</div>
            <br><br>
    </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
    <!-- Footer -->
    <section id="contactUs" class="signup-section">
<footer class="page-footer font-small stylish-color-dark pt-4">

  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

    <!-- Grid row -->
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">

        <!-- Content -->
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">News & Events</h5>
          <div class="container">
        <?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT postTitle, postSlug FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC LIMIT 5');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postSlug'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></p>'; 
}
?>
</div>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Useful Links</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">News & Events</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Franchise Opportunities</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">About Us</a>
          </li>
            <li>
            <a href="admin/login.php">Admin Log-in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Get Started</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Home Care Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Book a Consultation</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Meet the team</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!">Jour our team</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto">

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mt-3 mb-4">Contact Us</h5>

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <p>The Care Company (SW) LTD
              <br>
              Little Spires
              <br>
              Totnes
              <br>
              Devon
              <br>
              TQ9 7QE</p>
          </li>
          <li>
           <p>Tel: 01548 521789</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

  </div>
  <!-- Footer Links -->

  <hr>

  <!-- Call to action -->
  <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline text-center py-2">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <a href="#projects" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger"  >Join Our Team</a>
        <a href="#wjs" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Find Home Care</a>
    </li>
      <hr style="margin-bottom: -30px !IMPORTANT">
  </ul>
  <!-- Call to action -->


</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-white small text-center text-black-50" style="background-color: #862d60 !IMPORTANT; color: white !IMPORTANT">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style=" margin-bottom: 20px !IMPORTANT">
                  <center>
               <a href="sitemap" style="margin-left: ; margin-right; display: inline;">Site Map</a>  |  <a href="pp" style="display: inline;">Privacy &amp; Cookies</a>  |  <a href="t&amp;c's" style="display: inline;">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                      </center>
              </div>
        <div class="social d-flex justify-content-center" style=" margin-bottom: 20px !IMPORTANT">
        <a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
            <a href="#" class="mx-2">
          <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/grayscale.min.js"></script> 
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't help you if you don't show your code. How would we know whats wrong?

Comment: @zgood Sorry was just going to input the code. Allways have issues importing it. Many thanks in advance

Comment: @GilloCoding you just copied and pasted what you're following. You need to post YOUR code.

Comment: @JoeSwindell ok ill do that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script for the Carousel is using jQuery, but it's trying to run before jQuery is loaded by the page. In its current state you need to move the Carousel script to AFTER the jQuery loading.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="grayscale.min.js"></script> 

  <script>
    $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 10000
    })

    $('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
        var minPerSlide = 3;
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<minPerSlide;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          }
    });
</script>
```

Now the jQuery functions  correctly and it moving like you desire.

I downloaded the JS and CSS for grayscale and linked to the CDNs of the libraries to confirm this would work for you.

Comment: Thanks so much bud, I new i was missing something, just need to fiddle with the css now. Seems to be showing in a vertical line not horizontal. But thanks so much again!